# Need a better input form in python

Tags: python, forms, input

```
t_l = []

n =  int(input("Enter your number : ")) 

t_l.append(n)

while n > 0 :
        
    num = int(input("Enter your number:"))
     
    t_l.append(num)
```

When the code is ran I can put unlimited inputs in it and each time. The form of inputs is like this:

```
Enter your number:5

Enter your number:7

Enter your number:61

Enter your number:92

Enter your number:76
```

But I want better a input form like this:

```
Enter your number #1:5

Enter your number #2:7

Enter your number #3:61

Enter your number #4:92

Enter your number #5:76
```

What should I do?

Comment: Your loop will never end like this.

Comment: A working form is better than a non-working form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can use `len()` with `f-string`

```py
t_l = []

n =  int(input(f"Enter your number #{len(t_l)+1}: ")) 

t_l.append(n)

while n > 0 :
        
    num = int(input(f"Enter your number #{len(t_l)+1}: ")) 
     
    t_l.append(num)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may this piece and it has limit on looping & formatted input as per your need.

```
    t_l = []
    n = int(input("Enter your number : "))
    t_l.append(n)
    index = 1
    while n > 0:
        num = int(input("Enter your number: #"+str(index)+":"))
        t_l.append(num)
        if num > n-1 :
            break
        index = index + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

## Infinite loop is handled and input modified

```
t_l = []
n =  int(input("Enter your number #{}:".format(len(t_l)+1))) 
t_l.append(n)

while n - 1 > 0 :  
    num = int(input("Enter your number #{}:".format(len(t_l)+1)))
    t_l.append(num)
    n = n-1
```